# PySpark difference between pyspark.sql.functions.col and pyspark.sql.functions.lit

Tags: pyspark, apache-spark-sql

I find it hard to understand the difference between these two methods from `pyspark.sql.functions` as the documentation on PySpark official website is not very informative. For example the following code:

```py
import pyspark.sql.functions as F
print(F.col('col_name'))
print(F.lit('col_name'))
```

The results are:

```
Column<b'col_name'>
Column<b'col_name'>
```

so what are the difference between the two and when should I use one and not the other?

Answer (score 30):

The [doc](http://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/scala/index.html#org.apache.spark.sql.functions$) says:

col:

*Returns a Column based on the given column name.*

lit:

*Creates a Column of literal value*

---

Say if we have a data frame as below:

```
>>> import pyspark.sql.functions as F
>>> from pyspark.sql.types import *

>>> schema = StructType([StructField('A', StringType(), True)])
>>> df = spark.createDataFrame([("a",), ("b",), ("c",)], schema)
>>> df.show()
+---+
|  A|
+---+
|  a|
|  b|
|  c|
+---+
```

If using `col` to create a new column from `A`:

```
>>> df.withColumn("new", F.col("A")).show()
+---+---+
|  A|new|
+---+---+
|  a|  a|
|  b|  b|
|  c|  c|
+---+---+
```

So `col` grabs an existing column with the given name, `F.col("A")` is equivalent to `df.A` or `df["A"]` here.

If using `F.lit("A")` to create the column:

```
>>> df.withColumn("new", F.lit("A")).show()
+---+---+
|  A|new|
+---+---+
|  a|  A|
|  b|  A|
|  c|  A|
+---+---+
```

While `lit` will create a constant column with the given string as the values.

Both of them return a Column object but the content and meaning are different.

Comment: Nicely explained and "diagrammed". I wonder if, given identifiers `myLit` and `myCol`, created by `F.lit(...)` and `F.col(...)` respectively, one could interrogate them to see what their future interpretations would be. Or perhaps it is a binding created by Catalyst and deeply buried. A `dir(...)` of both doesn't surface any difference, although this example proves there is.

Answer (score 1):

To explain in a very succinct manner, `col` is typically used to refer to an existing column in a DataFrame, as opposed to `lit` which is typically used to set the value of a column to a literal

To illustrate with an example:
Assume i have a DataFrame `df` containing two columns of `IntegerType`, `col_a` and `col_b`

1. If i wanted a column `total` which were the sum of the two columns:

```py
df.withColumn('total', col('col_a') + col('col_b'))
```

2. Instead of i wanted a column `fixed_val` having the value "Hello" for all rows of the DataFrame `df`:

```py
df.withColumn('fixed_val', lit('Hello'))
```